# Search for Value & Key in Mac App

Tags: xcode, macos, core-data, key-value-coding

I have a Mac application that validates user credentials , Name & PIN. Using `CoreData`, how do I reference the `key` from a particular `value`? For example, in the database, John Doe has a PIN of 1234. When the user chooses their name, they enter their pin and hit the login button. If the pin matches what `CoreData` has in its database, it allows the user to continue. I have everything set up and ready to go, I just can't figure out how to get the PIN value from Core Data. I will then compare it to the string value entered in by the user to validate the user's credentials. Its probably something simple but I can't figure it out. Entity name: `Employee` Attributes: 'employeeName' & 'employeePin'.

```
- (IBAction)loginButton:(NSButton *)sender {
NSString *name = self.chooseNameBox.selectedCell;
NSString *pass = self.pinEntryField.stringValue;

context.???
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You hold the PIN in plaintext and not as a hash???

Comment: @trojanfoe Sure. Its just a personal application not being implemented for the app store or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup a fetch request like this:

```
NSError *aError = nil;
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                          entityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:self.currentManagedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
NSPredicate* entriesPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"employeeName = %@", name];
NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];

[request setPredicate:entriesPredicate];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

NSArray *employeeArray = [self.currentManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&aError];

EmployeeObject *retrievedEmployee = [employeeArray lastObject];
NSString *retrievedPin = retrievedEmployee.employeePin;
```

Also, I agree with @trojanfoe you need to hash the pin before inserting it into the database.

Comment: Where did you get `EmployeeObject` from? Its causing a compiler error.  `Use of undeclared identifier EmployeeObject`

Comment: Sorry, I always subclass my core data entities and use a separate class for it. If you don't do that, just swap out 'EmployeeObject' for 'NSManagedObject'

Comment: Thanks! It cleared up that error. Now it gives me another. `Property employeePin not found on object of type NSManagedObject *`

Comment: lol, that's probably why you should subclass your entity objects. It's easy. Just click on your core data model in XCode. Select the entity you want to subclass (you probably only have one), go up to Editor->Create NSManagedObject Subclass..., then click 'Create'. It should add two files to your project. Import the header file into your main application header file, and you should be able to create objects with that class name. If the header XCode creates is called 'EmployeeObject' then that is what you name your employee object, like I did above. If it has a different class name, use that.

Comment: USER ERROR haha I got it! Thanks! I did subclass it in the beginning I just forgot that I did! Thanks again!

Comment: i would like to know what will happen if core data value dosn't match..i am doing the same authentication but i am getting exception when value dosnt match

Comment: @Nvork what value are you speaking of? The entity name? The predicate? The sort descriptor? Those values are not checked before they are sent to the request, so you will get errors if they don't match EXACTLY (case-sensitive). I would highly recommend you create global static strings for the various keys you use. That will eliminate typo errors in the key strings.